# Excel spreadsheeet help.. Extracting data

Tags: excel, list, extract

I have a large list of 6000+ names and emails..

The list looks like

First,"Last","john.smith@uky.edu"

It's all in the first cell.

I need to separate these names from their emails, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Christian London Fielden,

You can use the Text To Columns command in Excel:

More information [here](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Split-names-by-using-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-39f7b055-6b39-4cb5-9512-13cc19b3a807#bmdelimit) or [here](http://best-excel-tutorial.com/55-advanced/95-text-to-columns)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try either this: https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Split-text-into-different-cells-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

or this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/split-a-column-of-text-HA103994003.aspx

other versions of Excel have this functionality as well... just look around the menu.\s